# How do I queue file for ffmpeg on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I need to encode/convert many videos on my (linux) server. And FFMPEG is resource intensive.
I am running Node.js and using fluent-ffmpeg

```
    const Ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
    videos.forEach(video=> {
        covertVideo(filename, (compressionResult)=>{
            //do something here
        });
    });
    function covertVideo(filename, callback){
        var ffmpeg = new FfmpegCommand(filename);
        ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(pathToFfmpeg);
        ffmpeg.addOptions("-threads 1")
        .fps(23)
        .complexFilter([
            "scale=w='if(gt(a,0.75),240,trunc(320*a/2)*2)':h='if(lt(a,0.75),320,trunc(240/a/2)*2)',pad=w=240:h=320:x='if(gt(a,0.75),0,(240-iw)/2)':y='if(lt(a,0.75),0,(320-ih)/2)':color=black[scaled]"
        ])
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
            return callback(false);
          })
        .on('end', function() {
            console.log('Compression finished !');
            return callback(true);
          })
        .save("./tmp/"+filename);
    }
```

So, I am using foreach loop to iterate through the file to be encoded. At each loop this function above is called.

**The problem here is that the foreach enters the second loop and start encoding when the first is still being encoded by FFMPEG thereby showing "Resource temporarily unavailable error".**

**Is there a way to queue files sent to FFMPEG so that next file is encoded when the previous is done and not concurrently.**

OR

**Is there a way for the Nodejs foreach to wait for ffmpeg to finish the first video before proceeding to the next loop.**

Comment: my node.js memory is fading, but it appears the issue is that you aren't waiting on ffmpeg. I'd make `covertVideo` to return `Promise` which is resolved by `ffmpeg`'s `'end'` and `'error`' events. Then, loop using a technique like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/4516027)

Comment: Great @kesh. You pointed in the right direction. I changed from using a callback to using a `Promise` for the covertVideo function. And resolved the Promise by ffmpeg's end and error event. Then when consuming the promise, I used async/await make sure each loop is completed from ffmpeg's end before entering the next loop. Thanks @kesh.